# Initializing static fields in C# for use in enum pattern

Tags: c#, initialization, enumeration, static-members

My question is actually about a way to work around how C# initializes static fields.  I need to do this, in my attempt to duplicate a Java style enum. The following is an example of the code that shows the problem:

A base class for all my enums to inherit from

```
public class EnumBase
{
    private int _val;
    private string _description;

    protected static Dictionary<int, EnumBase> ValueMap = new Dictionary<int, EnumBase>();

    public EnumBase(int v, string desc)
    {
        _description = desc;
        _val = v;
        ValueMap.Add(_val, this);
    }

    public static EnumBase ValueOf(int i)
    {
        return ValueMap[i];
    }

    public static IEnumerable<EnumBase> Values { get { return ValueMap.Values; } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("MyEnum({0})", _val);
    }
}
```

A sample of an enumerated set:

```
public sealed class Colors : EnumBase
{
    public static readonly Colors Red    = new Colors(0, "Red");
    public static readonly Colors Green  = new Colors(1, "Green");
    public static readonly Colors Blue   = new Colors(2, "Blue");
    public static readonly Colors Yellow = new Colors(3, "Yellow");

    public Colors(int v, string d) : base(v,d) {}
}
```

This is where the problem is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("color value of 1 is " + Colors.ValueOf(2)); //fails here
    }
}
```

The above code fails because EnumBase.ValueMap contains zero items, because none of the constructors for Color have been called yet.

It seems like this shouldn't be that hard to do, it is possible in Java, I feel like I must be missing something here?

Answer (score 7):

That pattern basically isn't going to work. Having a single dictionary isn't going to be a good idea, either - I suspect you want to make your `EnumBase` abstract and generic:

```
public abstract class EnumBase<T> where T : EnumBase<T>
```

That could then have a *protected* static member which can be effectively "published" through each derived class:

```
public abstract class EnumBase<T> where T : EnumBase<T>
{
    protected static T ValueOfImpl(int value)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Color : EnumBase<Color>
{
    // static fields

    // Force initialization on any access, not just on field access
    static Color() {}

    // Each derived class would have this.
    public static Color ValueOf(int value)
    {
        return ValueOfImpl(value);
    }
}
```

This then forces you to access the `Color` class itself... at which point the fields will be initialized, due to the static initializer.

There are quite a few things to be done to make all of this work, unfortunately :(

Comment: My actual implementation has it as Abstract, and generic, and Colors as sealed.  But yeah, after beating my head against the wall it appears I am stuck with 'enum', custom attributes, a and templated EnumExtension class that uses reflection. That'll be some clean code :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you were trying so say in code is simply:

```
public enum Colors
    {
        [Description("Red")]
        Red = 0,
        [Description("Green")]
        Green = 1,
        [Description("Blue")]
        Blue = 2
        //etc...
    }
```

You can easily read the Description attribute using reflection.. You can even create an extention methods for the Colors enums if you want and implement something similar to ValueOf as an extention method

Comment: But C# enums are very limited compared to Java's so I was hoping to come up with something similar to Java's.  I am not sure how I would implement ValueOf(int x) as an extension method. Though it wouldn't be needed anyway, as int's can be case to enums.  But still, that is one limitation of extensions; you can't have class methods.  i.e. MyEnum.DoSomthing(5).  You can do this MyEnum instance; instance.DoSomething(5), but that is different. Either way, I realize it does look like I'll have to use plain old enums, with a templated extension class.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with MyEnum.DoSomething. Enums (in C++ and C#) are just a structured list of numbers, not a set of data and operations (like a class).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the point of a static member. A static member is a member of the *type*, not the instance.

When you call `Colors.ValueOf()` you are only accessing the type, an instance has not been created of that type - the instance constructors won't be called at all.

You could create an extension method for the `Color` enum if you just want to be able to define some behaviours. You could get the enum from a value simply by casting from its `int` base:

```
public enum Color { Red = 0, Green = 1, Blue = 2, Yellow = 3 }

public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static string GetString(this Color color)
    {
        return string.Format("MyEnum({0})", color);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("color value of 1 is " + ((Color)1).GetString());
```

You'll also find a number of useful methods in the `System.Enum` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx). There are methods there to parse from `string` or to get a collection of all the possible `enum` values.

Comment: But shouldn't the static constructor for Colors, which will initialize all of those static member variables (which are, in turn, colors) have been called?

Comment: Yes, sorry I've better qualified that now. Only the instance constructors won't be called.

Comment: I still don't understand why the instance constructors won't be called. They are instantiated in the static constructor, which is called, right? What am I not getting here?

Comment: No, an instance constructor is run when an instance of a type is created. A static constructor is run after the type is loaded and before any type member is accessed.

Comment: Right. And the static constructor includes initialization of static members. So when Colors.ValueOf(2) is run, the static Colors constructor will have already been run, which includes initialization of static members, like "public static readonly Colors Red    = new Colors(0, "Red");" By initializing that static member, the instance constructor of Colors is run.

Is the difference that ValueOf is really on the base class, and calling it through Colors doesn't actually gaurantee that the static constructor on Colors be called?

Comment: Is is possible to write static extension methods? All the examples I see on extension methods show that as (fake) instance methods.

Comment: @Sheamus, that's right - in the example I've created an instance of the enum - `(Color)1`.

Comment: @SirPentor - I believe that, as only a member of `EnumBase` is called, only the `EnumBase` static cctor will be called.

Comment: Also, in the example given. If you were to explicitly call a static member on `Colors` (to constructor all of its members) - you could then use `Colors.ValueOf()` as the type has been loaded. Ugly anti-pattern tho :)

Comment: @DavidNeale--yeah I think that's right. Now I get why it didn't work.  Also, completely agree--this is a really bad way to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, and it is actually quite useful.  You get type safety when setting variables and the ability to search dynamically.  I'd prefer to see less code in the child class, but none the less, it works well.  You could also expand upon this and grow the number of fields in the EnumBase and also override operators and the ToString methods, etc.  You could also throw more generics into the mix.  It's Enums on steroids.

**Edited: Read bottom of entry**

EnumBase:

```
public class EnumBase
{
    public int Val { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    private static readonly Dictionary<int, EnumBase> ValueMap = new Dictionary<int, EnumBase>();

    protected EnumBase(int v, string desc)
    {
        Description = desc;
        Val = v;
    }

    protected static void BuildDictionary<T>()
    {

        var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            ValueMap.Add(((EnumBase)field.GetValue(null)).Val, (EnumBase)field.GetValue(null));
        }
    }

    public static EnumBase ValueOf(int i)
    {
        return ValueMap[i];
    }
}
```

Colors:

```
public sealed class Colors : EnumBase
{
    public static readonly Colors Red = new Colors(0, "Red");
    public static readonly Colors Green = new Colors(1, "Green");
    public static readonly Colors Blue = new Colors(2, "Blue");
    public static readonly Colors Yellow = new Colors(3, "Yellow");

    public Colors(int v, string d) : base(v, d)
    {
    }

    static Colors()
    {
        BuildDictionary<Colors>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//example of type safety
var i = Colors.Blue.Val;

//example of dynamic search
Console.WriteLine(Colors.ValueOf(1).Description);
```

**Edited:**

The above code doesn't work if you inherit from EnumBase more than once (which is a huge problem).  The static methods aren't inherited, i.e. all child classes will just add more records to the static base class Dictionary.

If the use case is strong enough, you can reuse the code instead of trying to use inheritance:

```
public sealed class Colors 
{
    public int Val { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    private static readonly Dictionary<int, Colors> ValueMap = new Dictionary<int, Colors>();

    static Colors()
    {
        BuildDictionary<Colors>();
    }

    private static void BuildDictionary<T>()
    {
        var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            ValueMap.Add(((Colors)field.GetValue(null)).Val, (Colors)field.GetValue(null));
        }
    }

    public static Colors ValueOf(int i)
    {
        return ValueMap[i];
    }

    private Colors(int v, string desc)
    {
        Description = desc;
        Val = v;
    }

    public static readonly Colors Red = new Colors(0, "Red");
    public static readonly Colors Green = new Colors(1, "Green");
    public static readonly Colors Blue = new Colors(2, "Blue");
    public static readonly Colors Yellow = new Colors(3, "Yellow");

}
```